# How to change Image of UIImageView in Tableview when it is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a Table view that I fill dynamically. The code for my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is :

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

UIImage * ImageFavorited = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Favorited"];

        UIImageView *ImageViewFavorited = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:7];
        ImageViewFavorited.image =ImageFavorited;

        ImageViewFavorited.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


        NSString *uiid = [[collectionFromData valueForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];
        MYTapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[MYTapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myFunction:)  ];
        tapped.data = uiid;
        tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [ImageViewFavorited addGestureRecognizer:tapped];

}
```

I know, I know, The `MYTapGestureRecognizer` is looking odd, I actually extended `UITapGestureRecognizer` so I can pass data with it. (Thank you StackOverFlow Users) , So my problem now is that I want to change the image of my clicked UIImageview after the user click on it. For now I detect the click in the `myfunction` function but I can't seem to find a way to change the image.

The code for `myfunction` is :

```
-(void)myFunction :(id) sender
{
    MYTapGestureRecognizer *tap = (MYTapGestureRecognizer *)sender;

    NSLog(@"data is  = %@", tap.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the myFunction to get the sender view:

```
[(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender view]
```

Then with that you can change that views properties, since in your case it’s a UIImageView, just cast it as a UIImageView and change the image property.

The completed solution would be:

```
[(UIImageView*) [(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender view]] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:”blah”]]
```

Comment: To be completly honest with you, I didn't quite understand what you are trying to say, I added the second line of code to my "Myfunction" function and it didn't work

Comment: Forgot the "*" after the UIImageView cast, I've edited it so it should work now.

Comment: What the above is doing is getting the view that was tapped (Which in this case was the UIImageView) so I cast it as a UIImageView so that I can call setImage on it. Make sure you have a valid image name in the imageNamed: function and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for this situation.

Instead of `UIImage` use `UIButton`and bind action in your `viewController`.
Set the button image of `default` and `Selected` state storyboard or by code as per what you do.

In `buttonAction`

```
sender.selected = !sender.selected;
tableView.raeloadData();
```

Thats All.
If still facing issue then let me knoe.